# Is it possible to paste code into PHP's interactive shell without a tab prompt?

Tags: php, interactive-shell

Whenever I've tried to paste large blocks of code (whole classes, long code snippets, etc.), I'm always greeted by this message for each line of code inputted:

```
Display all 3616 possibilities? (y or n)
```

I'm pretty sure it's because my code is indented and it's triggering the tab functionality by pasting the tab character. If this was just a visual annoyance, I wouldn't care, but it tends to randomly stop processing lines in the middle of a method and then demands that I type `y` or `n`.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32885/disable-tab-autocompletion-in-interactive-mode   older answer, but probably still valid

Comment: cant you just write a file and call it with `php fiel.php` ?

Comment: That's funny you link that @MarcB, because as I was posting this question I thought, "Is Stack Overflow the best place for this?" I didn't think it belonged on Super User or any of the other Stack Exchanges better though.

Comment: probably half-half. technically not really programming, but it's related close enough to programming to count.

Comment: I could @Dagon, but it's about convenience. As a programmer, I am inherently lazy and don't want to do that (especially if it's only a quick 2-second test). I could also paste the text into Notepad2 (if I wasn't on a Mac) and then remove indents, but that might require selecting each indentation layer.